# An emptying tank of parabolic profile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

A tank of parabolic profile and length L $= 4$m (see fig. below) is pierced at the bottom of a drain of surface $A = 10$ cm$^2$. If the water level is $h = 1$ m at the initial time $~t_0=0~$, how long will it take for the tank level to drop to $~h(t_1)=0.5$ m

Consider $g = 9.81$ m/s$^2$

[image: Figure of parabolic profile tank]

Representation of a parabolic tank with a surface drain $A=10$ cm$^2$ located at the point $~x=2, ~y=z=0~$. The area describing the shape of the tank corresponds to the equation $~z=αy^2~$ where $~α=1/m~$ if $~z~$ and $~y~$ is expressed in meters.

I tried to solve it but my teacher said that's not the right answer. Here is what I did:

[image: My solution]

In the step $2$ he said I was suppose to have that: [image]

But I did not get it where it comes from and how can I integrate that equation because I have $~\dfrac{dh}{dt}~$ and $~\dfrac{dv}{dt}~$ in the same equation?

Comment: $v=\dfrac{dh}{dt}$

Comment: ok but then i have have dh/dt on both sides? doesn't make sense?

Comment: No $\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{d^{2}h}{dt^{2}}$

Comment: so I will have like : d^2h/dt = 2L*squareroot(..) and now I integrate both side from h0 to h1?

Comment: You have to solve ,second order differential equation but I don’t think you get analytical solution?

Comment: I need to find "t" the time it takes to empty half of it. Can you show it?

Comment: I will try to calculate it like this:

first  obtain the Tank volume $V=\frac{2}{3}\,h^{3/2}\,L$

second , you can obtain the time t from this equation 

$\frac{V}{t}=A\,\sqrt{2\,g\,h(t1)}$

Comment: where did you get 2/3*h^3/2?

Comment: v/t = A*squareroot(..) that's why I did also in 3rd step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the liquid level is h(t), the volume of liquid is $$V=L\int_{-\sqrt{h/a}}^{+\sqrt{h/a}}{(h-z)dy}=L\int_{-\sqrt{h/a}}^{+\sqrt{h/a}}{(h-ay^2)dy}=\frac{2L}{3\sqrt{a}}h^{3/2}$$
The rate of change of volume is then:
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{L}{\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{h}\frac{dh}{dt}=-A\sqrt{2gh}$$
So the factor of 2 in your teacher's equation looks wrong.